# Firebase not accepting JWT acquired from Google Identity Platform's REST API: 'The custom token format is incorrect.'

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter-web, google-identity

I'm trying to enable multifactor auth in my Flutter project, which is only targeting the web platform. As I understand, the latest version of the FlutterFire SDK does not support MFA. This is why I'm trying to use the [Google Identity Platform APIs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest) to add the feature to my app.

I can already acquire a token from the REST API, but when passing it to the signInWithCustomToken() method, I always get this error: 'The custom token format is incorrect...'

Here is how I'm trying to sign a user in:

1. Use [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to post to https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword
2. Start MFA by posting to https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/mfaSignIn:start
3. Get the SMS verification code from the message sent to the user's phone number.
4. Post to https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/accounts.mfaSignIn/finalize
   with the SMS verification code.
5. Get the `idToken` from the response body.
6. Pass the acquired `idToken` to the `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken()` method.

Looking at this Firebase doc, it appears that the token I get from GIP REST API is formatted differently.

Is there anything I can do so that the Firebase SDK accepts the tokens I get from the Google Identity Platform REST API?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase `signInWithCustomToken()` method takes [a token generated by the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens), not a Google Identity token.

Tokens returned by GCIP (Google Cloud Identity Platform) are the same Auth ID tokens used by Firebase. After calling `finalizeMfa` you have essentially signed into Firebase, and if you begin to use the SDK, you'll see that it works at this point without any conversion.

Comment: Does this mean that the FlutterFire SDK will automatically recognize that there is a signed in user, even if the sign in process took place using the REST APIs?

Comment: If not, how can I let FlutterFire know that I have made the user sign in using the GCIP REST APIs? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just using the SDK? Start with the use case you want to solve so we don't have to play merry-go-round : D  See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)